# SOS-Berlin JobScheduler process queue logic

Tags: performance, job-scheduling

We're running into an issue with the SOS-Berlin JobScheduler running on Windows that is difficult to diagnose* and I would appreciate any guidance.

*Difficult because I don't know Scala (though I do know C++ and Java). It's difficult to navigate this code-base (some of it's in German).

We have a process-class called Foo, that will sometimes burst up outside the limit of how many processes can be run. So, for example, we limit the process-class to 30 processes and 60 want to run. This leaves 30 running and 30 "waiting for process."

The problem is that JobScheduler doesn't seem to prioritize the 30 that are waiting for a process. Instead, any new job that gets fired after the burst receives processes, leaving some jobs waiting indefinitely. Once the number of jobs "waiting for process" hits zero, the jobs clear out immediately.

Further, it seems that when there are a large number of jobs "waiting for process," the run time for tasks doubles or triples. A job that normally takes 20 seconds to run, will spike to 1-2 minutes, further amplifying the issue as processes are not released back to the pool.

Admittedly, we're running an older version of JS, which we're planning to upgrade this/next week. However, I'm wondering if there is something fundamental we're missing. We've turned down the logging, looked for DB locks, added memory to the heap, shut-down some other processes on the server. We've also increased the process pool, but we don't want to push it too far, lest we crush the server. Nothing seems to be alleviating the issue.

Any tuning help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow-up, we determined the cause of the issue.

Another user had been using the temp directory to store intermediate generated files. The user was not clearing out these files, resulting in 100's of thousands of files in the directory. They were not very large so we didn't notice. For some reason Job Scheduler started to choke based on this. I'm not clear on the reasons.

Clearing the temp directory, scolding the user, and fixing his script fixed the issue.